# HttpClient.GetStringAsync(url) throwing "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send." Windows 8.1 C#

Tags: c#, exception, windows-8.1, httpclient

I'm creating a new Windows 8.1 App just for testing this error I am getting. 
The app has only one function:

```
private async void TestMethod()
        {
            try
            {                       
                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https:// url ");                    
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException e)
            {
                string s = e.InnerException.Message;
            }
        }
```

It is always entering the catch and throwing "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send." I found a lot of questions mentioning that but no solution worked for me since this is a Windows 8.1 Store App not an ASP.NET app.

The Uri I am using opens in the Browser and is functioning very well.

I even got to this article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/915599 but no solution. Anyone has encoutered this problem before?

**Edit:**

I changed the method to use `async Task`

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at System.Net.PooledStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
  at HttpRequestTestApp.MainPage.d__0.MoveNext()
```

Comment: did you try any other url endpoints? are you getting same error?

Comment: Post the *full* exception (ie use `e.ToString()`), not just the message of the inner exception. Also check the status code of the response. Is it a 4xx, 5xx? Use Fiddler to capture the raw request and the server response. If the server crashes and doesn't even return a full response, there's no point in changing the client code.

Comment: PS How are you calling this method? `async void` means "fire-and-forget".  It can't be awaited. Your program or test framework probably terminates before the test completes. Use `async Task` instead. `async void` should  be used for event handlers or similar methods only

Comment: please check my edited answer

Comment: Have you tried changing the url to be something like https://google.com, something you know should work? Also, change the return type from `void` to `Task`. That's the correct return type for async methods.

Comment: I did change the url to https://www.google.com and it works and return a return a response.

Comment: If google works and your original does not use fiddler to capture the headers from your browser to that url.  You may need to provide them in your call.

Comment: There's no authentication to be made on this request so I should use headers. Plus I am using the same function with the same url in my WindowsPhone 8.1 app and it is working but in this Windows 8.1 App it is throwing an exception.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I can't get the StatusCode of the response since it enters the catch immediately  `HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https:// url ");`

Comment: The exception message clearly shows that the *server* closed the connection. What server is that? What does its log show? Have you tried debugging the *server*?

Comment: Update to .NET framework 4.6 or higher - TLS 1.2 is supported there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out I was using Windows.Net.Http that doesn't support TLS1.2. Windows.Web.Http does.

Comment: `System.Net.Http`

Comment: force setting the ssl protocol by adding: ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;